# How do i pass a function pointer to a function.

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

Hey so i am trying to figure out how i pass a function pointer to a function stored within a struct. The following is the typedef

```
struct menu_item
{
    char name[ITEM_NAME_LEN+1];
    BOOLEAN (*func)(struct vm*);

};
```

The function i am trying to pass has the following prototype.

```
void print_list(struct vm_node  *root);
```

with the defintion of the file being:

```
void print_list(struct vm_node  *root) {
    while (root) {
        printf("%s",root->data->id);
        root = root->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct menu_item item;
item.func = &print_list;
```

As simple as that. However `BOOLEAN (*func)(struct vm*);` needs to be changed to `void (*func)(struct vm_node *);` to match the destination function.

Comment: The address of operator isn't needed at `&print_list`. `print_list` decays to a function pointer similar to how an array decays to a pointer.

Comment: @krypton the func will have to accept various other functions which will return other types.

Comment: @tangrs: with ampersand is a more correct way of understanding.

Comment: @Krypton that's fair enough but it does look cleaner without it IMHO.

Comment: @tangrs: yeah, it's a personal preference though.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf: if you want it to accept various types function prototype, simply declare as `void (*func)()`, but then you would need to do type enforcing to prevent compiler warnings.

Comment: @Krypton Wouldn't it be `void (*func)(void *param)` instead?

Comment: @AntonH the params doesn't matter as type enforcing will take place in the end.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf `the func will have to accept various other functions which will return other types` - this is generally a **bad** idea. But if you really _must_ do this, you can create a `union` of possible return types, and have all your functions return that union.

Answer (score 0):

functions are sort of like arrays so you can just do

```
menu_item.func = print_list;
```

just like you would do with an array

```
int arr[20];
int *ptr;
ptr = array /*
```

Comment: Do you know what the above line does?

Comment: OP wants a function pointer as far as I can see, not the result of a function call.